# Вычисление разницы элементов списка

Tags: python, алгоритм

На вход подается список из кортежей. Каждый кортеж содержит по два числа(int). Нужно отсеять "похожие" вхождения.

Пример. На вход подается список вида :

```
d = [(55, 276), (55, 277), (104, 38), (104, 39), (104, 514), (104, 515), (105, 38), (105, 514), (210, 514), (210, 515)]
```

Нулевой и первый элемент почти идентичны, т.е. не выполнятся условие :

```
(abs(d[0][0] - d[1][0]) + abs(d[0][1] - d[1][1])) <= 10
```

, значит первый элемент можно удалить из списка. И дальше перебором ищем и удаляем похожие элементы. На выходе будет список:  `[(55, 277), (105, 514), (210, 515), (105, 38)]`

Есть ли вариант ускорить выполнение программы и решить задачу без двух вложенных циклов ?

```
def remove_similar_coordinates(data: list) -> list:
    answer = []
    length_data = len(data)
    for x in range(length_data - 1):
        flag = True
        for y in range(x+1, length_data):
            if (abs(data[x][0] - data[y][0]) + abs(data[x][1] - data[y][1])) <= 10 :
                flag = False
                break
        if flag:
            answer.append(data[x])
    if length_data > 0:
        answer.append(data[-1])
    return answer

data = [(55, 276), (55, 277), (104, 38), (104, 39), (104, 514), (104, 515), (105, 38), (105, 514), (210, 514), (210, 515)]
remove_similar_coordinates(data)
```

Output: `[(55, 277), (105, 38), (105, 514), (210, 515)]`

Comment: https://onecompiler.com/python/3wzjhd8x8

Comment: Спасибо, поправил :)

Comment: Конкретно ли эти числа должны быть в результате или порядок чисел и их значение не важно?

Comment: порядок не важен, важно отсеять лишнее

Comment: Такое может быть? `[(55, 276), (210, 514), (104, 38), (104, 514)]`

Comment: да, лишь бы были уникальные(с разницей по элементам более 10)

Comment: Классная задача, на самом деле. И совсем не такая простая как кажется.

Comment: А список отсортирован, или это случайно так получилось?

Comment: В моей задаче входные данные отсортированы по первому элементу в кортеже (Поиск шаблонов на изображении возвращает координаты Y,X и стартует из верхнего левого угла. Простенькая реализация компьютерного зрения для своих нужд)

Answer (score 4):

С использованием `set`:

```
d = [(55, 276), (55, 277), (104, 38), (104, 39), (104, 514), (104, 515), (105, 38), (105, 514), (210, 514), (210, 515)]


class Wr:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

    def __eq__(self, o):
        return abs(self.v[0] - o.v[0]) + abs(self.v[1] - o.v[1]) <= 10

    def __hash__(self):
        return True


print( list(i.v for i in set( Wr(v) for v in d )) )
```

Добавляем оверрайд оператора `=`, чтобы при добавлению в сэт значения сравнивались.

Comment: Это круто ! Создать новый объект и запихать в сет - супер оригинально :) Сейчас проверю на больших размерах , сравню скорости.

Comment: У вас `__eq__` нетранзитивный, из-за этого могут быть проблемы.

Comment: а так не легче: `print([i.v for i in {Wr(v) for v in d}])`?

Comment: @Danis, лично мне словами читабельнее как-то

Comment: На 10к элементов в списке вариант с двумя циклами ~ 15 сек, вариант  entithat ~ 14 сек. Только размеры выходных списков не совпадают. У себя уже нашел один баг, исправил, но размеры ответов все равно не совпадают...

Comment: Код теста : https://onecompiler.com/python/3wzjnqx3d

Comment: @Alexander, мой код немного медлит из-за того, что мы потом проходимся по каждому элементу в сэте и трансформируем его. Если вам надо кол-во уникальных элементов, то можно без листа, просто `len(set(...))`. Потому что я пару раз запустил для 10к, результат в на 30% быстрее у меня, минимум. А насчет правильных ответов, разве что вручную считать, если нет тестов..

Comment: Да, верно, на 30% производительнее. Осталось баг у себя найти.

Comment: Вроде, разобрался, спасибо :)

Comment: `__eq__` не транзитивный - это не могут быть проблемы. Это есть проблема, которая закончится неуправляемым некорректным сетом. Хорошо если будет просто тормозить. Плохо если будет бросать исключения. Катастрофа, если будет ронять интерпретатор.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, стесняюсь спросить, но что значит транзитивный?

Comment: Транзитивный значит для любых `a`, `b`, `c` верно что из `a == b and b == c` следует `a == c`. У вас не так.

Comment: @entithat, поправьте конечно. Замечу что проблема "приблизительного равенства" старая, и никогда нормально не была разрешена. "приблизительное равенство" просто не будет работать с сетом.

Comment: Из-за постоянного `__hash__` вариант с сетом не будет быстрее чем вариант с двумя циклами. Из-за нетранзитивного `__eq__` сет будет делать ошибки при удалении/добавлении элементов. И **это не поправить**.

Answer (score 2):

Задача разрешима за линейное время. Можно подобрать входной набор точек, когда константа будет сравнительно велика, но время всё равно будет линейное.

**Решётка**

На плоскости нарисуем решётку из квадратов размера `d` (расстояние на котором считаем точки близкими). Точки поместим в квадраты. Заметим что если две точки отстоят не далее чем на `d`, то они или в одном квадрате или в двух соседних через сторону или вершину.

Если хотим для точки `q` отыскать близкие, нам надо просмотреть только точки из девяти квадратов, остальные точки слишком далеки.

**Код**

Заведём словарь в котором ключём будут координаты квадрата, значением - множество точек в квадрате. Каждую новую точку будем сравнивать со всеми точками из девяти соседних квадратов. В любом случае, после сравнения, новая точка добавляется в "свой" квадрат.

В худшем случае точку придётся сравнить с `9 * d^2` другими точками. Для `d = 10` это девятьсот точек. Много, но сложность линейная, это важнее.

Эта реализация из пары близких точек пропускает первую, удаляет вторую. В исходной постановке задачи наоборот. По этому в конце есть код, который подает точки на вход задом наперед и переворачивает ответ:

```
points = [(55, 276), (55, 277), (104, 38), (104, 39), (104, 514),
          (104, 515), (105, 38), (105, 514), (210, 514), (210, 515)]


def dist(p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    return abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2)


def key(p, d):
    x, y = p
    return x // d, y // d


def remove_near_items(points, d):
    dataset = {}

    def check_near_items(q):
        kx, ky = key(q, d)
        for x in range(kx - 1, kx + 2):
            for y in range(ky - 1, ky + 2):
                for p in dataset.get((x, y), frozenset()):
                    if dist(q, p) <= d:
                        return True
        return False

    for p in points:
        if not check_near_items(p):
            yield p
        dataset.setdefault(key(p, d), set()).add(p)


print(*reversed(tuple(remove_near_items(reversed(points), 10))))
```

> ```
> $ python list_item_difference.py 
> (55, 277) (105, 38) (105, 514) (210, 515)
> ```